# Disable CSS/SASS/SCSS warning in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

When using SASS maps in Visual Studio it always shows the error

`Unexpected character sequence`

I realize that this is due to Visual Studio not supporting SASS maps but there are also ways of suppressing compiler warnings, usually by adding `#pragma warning disable(####)` but there are two problems when trying to do this in the CSS editor. First `#` designates an ID and second the warning output does not contain a code.

Do I need to add something to my lint or is there a way to suppress these?

Comment: It /really/ annoying that they build in language validation without a compiler.  Exactly /what/ are they validating against? I switched from Web Essentials to gulp + gulp-sass because I don't think it's kept up to date much

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any extension in Visual studio to compile sass file ? By default VS do not have any config to compile SASS or SCSS to CSS. Maybe you install some extension like this [WebCompiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler)

Comment: Yes I have the `Web Essentials 2019` installed, everything compiles and works fine, it's only a syntax error while using maps, the problem is other warnings tend to get lost when these show up so I would like to hide them.

Comment: for me there is no css/scss compiler of any sort installed.

Answer (score 0):

in Tools > options > text editor > scss > advanced:
there is a section called "validation" , set "enable validation" to false.

there is also a section called "css" in the options.

Comment: Wouldn't that disable all SCSS validation including things like functions, mixins etc? I would like to keep those enabled, I would like to just get rid of the map error message, not disable the validation totally

Comment: yes is does. do it if that what you want.