# How to set grid-template-areas in sass (node-sass)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sass, node-sass

I have an ASP.NET project, which I used Sass.

I used [WebCompiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64) to compile my .scss files.

The SCSS code shown here is valid CSS, and does not ruin my app when I run it. (I created a fresh ASP.NET project with VS2019 .NET 5 and VS2022 .NET 6, and they both have the same warning)

[image]

Since WebCompiler is using [node-sass](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/blob/586295ba3c3107b7613dcb5a02667aad817045d4/build/build.cmd#L18), I checked [the official node-sass repo](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues) for a solution regarding this. Unfortunately, there was none.

Is there a way to remove these **warnings** when setting a value for `grid-template-areas`?

If I **completely** remove all warnings (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> SCSS -> Advanced -> Enable Validation), I won't know potential errors/warnings in the future. I just want to remove this *warning*.

(Or do I need an **extension** for this?)

---

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070658/disable-css-sass-scss-warning-in-visual-studio-2019) is similar to my problem. The problem of that question is about sass maps, and mine is about grid-template-areas.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've got exactly the same problem

Comment: Won't fix!? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CSS-Error-in-SCSS-File--Formatting-Issue/10044672